# How to disable developer tools with Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView [ Windows ]

Tags: maui, webview2

How can I disable the developer tools for a Maui WebView control ?   With Xamarin WebView2 it is quite easy with CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled.

In fact, I believe at least on Windows, the Maui WebView is based on CoreWebView2.  Is there a way to access the CoreWebView2.Settings directly ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... I did find a solution.  It seems to be a question of setting the AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled at the correct time.

Not ideal, but setting the first time a Navigating event is called works. (perhaps someone knows a better way to do this)

```
 WebView wv = new WebView();
 wv.Navigating += Wv_Navigating ;

private void Wv_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
  WebView webview = (WebView)sender;
  CoreWebView2 coreWebView2 = (webview.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2).CoreWebView2;
  coreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
  webview.Navigating -= Wv_Navigating;
}
```

Comment: Note:  with xamarin, this can be done on the CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event.  Was not able to figure out how to do it in Maui

Answer (score 1):

The `WebView` in the maui is the WinUI3's `WebView2` on the windows platform. According to [this link](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2118), you can try the following code to disable the developer tools on the windows platform in the maui.

In the xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" .../>
```

In the code behand:

```
#if WINDOWS
   (webview.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2).CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
#endif
```

I have done a sample to test this, the code was hit when I deleted `#if`. But it can't disable the developer tools. It seems a bug for WebView2, you can report it on the github.